# thumbnail in .list-group-item

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to show a thumbnail image on the right side of a list-group-item in a bootstrap list. Need to keep label left justified and image right justified. Is my .checkbox throwing off my alignment and/or placement.

```
<a href="#acet" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" style="background-color: lightyellow;">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label style="font-size: 1.5em">
             ACETAMINOPHEN
        </label>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <img src="/images/IMG_0741.JPG" alt="DRUGS" class="img-thumbnail max-width: 10%;">
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: can you give an example? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: do i need to put the image in the label to align it as I want?

Comment: it looks like you have css in your `class` attribute.

Comment: @BarclayVision Please add CSS code to your post. Without it, it is very hard to give an answer.